# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una foto de perfil al enviar un correo con php?

Tags: email

¿Cómo puedo agregar una foto de perfil al enviar un correo  con php?
El código que uso  y la librería lo uso así:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Host = 'countier.com.mx';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $usuario['usuarioSMTP'];
$mail->Password = $usuario['passwordSMTP'];
$mail->Subject = 'Informacion uniformes ejecutivos COUNTIER';
$mail->msgHTML($cadenalink);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    
} else 
{
   echo "Envío exitoso";
}
```

Pero no sé como agregar que llegue una foto de perfil en  el correo, como las que salen  en el correo de gmail.

Comment: acaso la foto de perfil no va asociada al perfil de la cuenta?

Comment: Cuando usas un software  "cliente"  puedes hacer eso, pero usando php para enviar el correo desde el servidor no sé  como hacerlo